# Single Sitecore instance with different project solutions

Tags: sitecore, single-instance, sitecore9

Is it possible to have different website project solutions with different file structures to be deployed on the same Sitecore instance?

If so what changes need to be done in Sitecore setup?

Comment: why would you like to do this?

Comment: Because the 2 different sites will be maintained or managed by different vendors..

Answer (score 1):

You can do this so long as the solutions are using different namespaces and various files are named differently. Make sure references, etc. are the same so there are no conflicts.

Comment: also can you help here like - if 2 different visual studio solution projects in separate location follows the same helix architecture can be deployed to the same sitecore instance ? If so then then how the config is differentiated ? please help

Comment: There should be no issue with multiple configurations in there, so long as they have unique names and don't overwrite each other's values. It's a little unconventional but nothing wrong doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. That is what [layered architecture and Helix & Habitat](https://helix.sitecore.net/principles/architecture-principles/layers.html) about.

Start by [watching 20 min video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKLpTMuQT4Y) to catch the basic ideas about layering.

It is totally fine to deploy different solutions/sites to the same physical Sitecore instance as long as each project plays by rules:

- Does not override basic templates
- Does not override basic system behaviors